# unable to write jarlistcache file in android..?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm having 4 problems..

1. `Right click>new android project>.....`. so ,and  it generates
   some additional files with the application files.. `"appcompat_v7"`
   every time i try to open a new project it creates another
   `"appcompat_v7_2"` and so on..and im unable to export these files as
   an apk file..it says link errors...
2. There is a warning shown in the console....

   > "unable to write jarlistcache file (followed by
   >   workspace address in the system)" every time i open eclipse...
3. `Android 4.4.2` loads every time when i open an existing layout...
4. Also im unable to start a new AVD.....

Comment: yup!! found a solution for it,the android SDK (Update-March 2014) 22.6 version is having some bugs.Just rolled back to my precious version of SDK and everything worked fine.......